# ¿Cuál es el equivalente a json.load pero con un csv?

Tags: python

Quisiera saber cuál es el equivalente a json.load pero con un csv

Intente con un .reader sin embargo aun no me cuadra

Comment: ¿Qué esperas como resultado? json.load() te retorna un diccionario o lista ¿qué debería retornarte un hipotético csv.load()? Lo más parecido es el método de pandas `pandas.load_csv()` y te retorna un dataframe ¿es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: Quiero cargar los datos de un csv para que luego, los puedo poner a cada uno de manera independiente en un json, entonces, ya traje el archivo, pero aun no encuentro la manera para que me lo lea de una forma que se pueda pasar. No se si me hice entender

Comment: creo que se entendería mejor si pudieras poner un pequeño ejemplo de datos en un csv y el json que querrías obtener a partir de él.